# Spouses won't move into house. Why?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I've tried getting several spouses (divorce mod) to move into my hearthfire house and none of them will do it. They all just go back to their default place instead of going to my house. After they go back to their house I always try again to see if they go then and they don't. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It might be the mod, try it with out the mod. I know for fact a lot of mods can really screw up commands to NPCs. If you have any companion mods or ones that add special companions, you may want to turn those off as well and try again.

Comment: I have the interesting NPCs mod... Think that could be an issue?

Comment: It's possible. You may want to also check your mod load order if you use nexus. I know my Follows wouldn't listen at all to me if i didn't have Ultimate Follower Overhaul, at the very bottom of my load list. Try that first maybe, if it doesn't help then you may need to turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

If your spouse won't move in, you can try a mod called something like "Spouses can live anywhere". You get a spell called mark new home and your spouse will move there. You can make them live in a cave if you wanted. It's really helpful for DLC estates and player home mods, so you can get them to move there. See if that helps.